# Finding index of vector from its original matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix of 2d lets assume the values of the matrix

```
a =
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    17    24     1     8    15
    11    18    25     2     9
```

This matrix is going to be divided into three different matrices randomly let say

```
b =
     17    24     1     8    15
     23     5     7    14    16

c =
      4     6    13    20    22
     11    18    25     2     9

d =
     10    12    19    21     3
     17    24     1     8    15
```

How can i know the index of the vectors in matrix d for example in the original matrix a,note that the values of the matrix can be duplicated.
for example if i want to know the index of  {10    12    19    21     3} in matrix a?
or the index of  {17    24     1     8    15} in matrix a,but for this one should return only on index value?
I would appreciate it so much if you can help me with this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ismember` with the `'rows'` option. For example:

```
tf = ismember(a, c, 'rows')
```

Should produce:

```
tf =
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     1
```

To get the indices of the rows, you can apply `find` on the result of `ismember` (note that it's redundant if you're planning to use this vector for matrix indexing). Here `find(tf)` return the vector `[3; 6]`.

If you want to know the number of the row in matrix `a` that matches a single vector, you either use the method explained and apply `find`, or use the second output parameter of `ismember`. For example:

```
[tf, loc] = ismember(a, [10 12 19 21 3], 'rows')
```

returns `loc = 4` for your example. Note that here `a` is the second parameter, so that the output variable `loc` would hold a meaningful result.

#### Handling floating-point numbers

If your data contains floating point numbers, The `ismember` approach is going to fail because floating-point comparisons are inaccurate. Here's a shorter variant of [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro)'s solution:

```
x = reshape(c', size(c, 2), 1, []);
tf = any(all(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a', x)) < eps), 3)';
```

Essentially this is a one-liner, but I've split it into two commands for clarity:

- `x` is the target rows to be searched, concatenated along the third dimension.
- `bsxfun` subtracts each row in turn from all rows of `a`, and the magnitude of the result is compared to some small threshold value (*e.g* [`eps`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)). If all elements in a row fall below it, mark this row as "1".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you build those divided matrices. For example:

```
a = magic(5);
d = a([2 1 2 3],:);
```

then the matching rows are obviously: 2 1 2 3

---

#### EDIT:

Let me expand on the idea of using `ismember` shown by [@EitanT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16716780/97160) to handle floating-point comparisons:

```
tf = any(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) all(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a, d(i,:)))<1e-9,2), ...
    1:size(d,1), 'UniformOutput',false)), 2)
```

not pretty but works :) This would be necessary for comparisons such as: `0.1*3 == 0.3`

(basically it compares each row of `d` against all rows of `a` using an absolute difference)

Comment: +1: Again, good idea about handling floating-point numbers. I've added my own variant for this :)