# Find permutations of rows in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am writing a piece of code that is supposed to find the rows in Nx3 matrix `E` that contains the values of Mx3 matrix `T`, but they are not necessarily in the same order. I wrote something which is working, but I am not happy with the style and wish to apply logical operations on the matrices using `ismember` and find, rather than the loop I am using:

```
E = [7 36 37; 9 1 5; 4 34 100; 4 12 33; 4 34 33];
T = [37 7 36; 4 34 33];      

for i=1:size(T,1)
    T(i,:) = sort(T(i,:));
end

for i=1:size(E,1)
    E(i,:) = sort(E(i,:));
end

res = zeros(size(T,1),1);
for i=1:size(T,1)
    a = ismember(E,t(i,:));    
    res(i,1) = find(sum(a,2)==3);
end
```

My idea was to sort each row of `E` and `T`, so they will be in the same order and then compare each row with a loop. However, I am trying to learn to write my code in a more MATLAB-style and wish to apply `ismember` and maybe find to do the same operation. Something like this:

```
a = sum(ismember(E,T(1,1))~=0,2);
b = sum(ismember(E,T(1,2))~=0,2);
c = sum(ismember(E,T(1,3))~=0,2);
r = find(a&b&c);
```

Any more graceful solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered [`ismember(A,B,'rows')`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) or perhaps [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)? Any solution based on sorting is probably going to be a little obfuscated, even if it's performant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `'rows'` option:

```
ismember(sort(E, 2), sort(T, 2), 'rows')
```

This produces a logical (boolean) vector that indicates which rows of matrix `T` (or any of their permutations) appear in matrix `E`. Note that each row is sorted independently to handle reordering.

If you need the indices of the row of `T`, use both outputs of `ismember`:

```
[tf, loc] = ismember(sort(E, 2), sort(T, 2), 'rows')
```

Note: if your data contains floating-point numbers, the `ismember` approach might fail, so you'll need to set a tolerance for comparison. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16716547#16716780) for a more robust alternative approach (and remember to sort your input matrices along the 2<sup>nd</sup> dimension first!).

#### Example

```
E = [7 36 37; 9 1 5; 4 34 100; 4 12 33; 4 34 33];
T = [37 7 36; 4 34 33];
[tf, loc] = ismember(sort(E, 2), sort(T, 2), 'rows');
```

The result is:

```
tf =          loc =
     1              1
     0              0
     0              0
     0              0
     1              2
```

Comment: Thanks again Eitan! This is the solution I was looking for. However, it skips 3 values (only finds 72 out of 75 indices for T). Will look into that in a minute.

Comment: The Matrices are of type double, but the values (displayed) as integers.

Comment: @TheodorBecker If your matrices comprise only pure integers, you shouldn't experience any problems with `ismember`. Check your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you ask using `bsxfun` and the `eq` function:

```
Esorted = sort(E, 2);
Tsorted = sort(T, 2);

rowsEq = bsxfun(@eq, Esorted, permute(Tsorted, [3 2 1]));
rowsEqInd = sum(rowsEq, 2) == size(T, 2);
EEqInd = sum(rowsEqInd, 3) > 0;
```

There is no need to sort each row of `E` and `T` in a loop - `sort` will do this for you. `rowsEq` is a 3-D array indicating the equality of the elements in each of the rows of `T` to each of the rows of `E`; where there are three `1`s in a row in this matrix, the rows of `E` and `T` are equal, so we sum up and test that the number of `1`s is 3 (or `size(T, 2)`). We're left with an array indicating the equality of each row of T separately, so the final `sum` combines these results to give what you desire.

Comment: Thanks wakjah, I tried this, but it only returns 0s in EEQInd for some reason. Also, Eitan's solution I prefer in this case!